# Jquery hover animate with jquery ui dialog

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, dialog, jquery-animate

I've a little but strange problem, with my animation realized with jquery and jquery UI. You can see a simple working demo below,

The problem comes out when you try to click on the "Click me" in the curtain and then click on "Close" in the popup shown. You will see both curtain and image go up. Do you know why?

Very thanks

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.box_product_image').hover(function () {
        $('.box_up-down', this).stop().animate({
            bottom: '0px'
        }, 300);
        $('.box_product_arrow', this).fadeOut(300);
    }, function () {
        $('.box_up-down', this).stop().animate({
            bottom: '-96px'
        }, 600);
        $('.box_product_arrow', this).fadeIn(300);
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#text', function () {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            height: 200,
            width: 200,
            modal: true,
            closeText: "close"
        });
    });
});
```

```css
*, ul, ol {
    border: 0 none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.box_product_border_image {
    border: 1px solid #d9d9d9;
    border-radius: 6px;
    height: 120px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 150px;
    margin: 50px;
}
.box_product_image {
    float: left;
    height: 120px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.box_up-down {
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    bottom: -96px;
    height: 100%;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    width: 150px;
}
.box_up-down > * {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 11px;
}
.box_product_name {
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 3px 0 0 10px;
}
.box_product_arrow {
    height: 19px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 15px;
    top: 3px;
    width: 10px;
}
.box_product_desc {
    margin: 5px 0 0 10px;
}
.box_product_desc ul {
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 10px;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.box_product_desc ul li {
    margin-bottom: 6px;
}
.box_product_desc ul li a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
#dialog {
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div class="box_product_border_image">
        <div class="box_product_image">
            <img width="150" height="120" src="http://www.microproject.com/wp-content/themes/NybergsMekVerstand/images/img03.png">
            <div class="box_up-down">
                <div class="box_product_name">Text</div>
                <div class="box_product_arrow" style="display: block;">
                   <img width="10" height="19" title="" alt="" src="http://tpgroupindia.com/images/arrow.png">
                </div>
                <div class="box_product_desc">
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Text</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Text</a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a id="text" href="#">Click me</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
            
            
<div id="dialog"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote your code (jQuery,HTML and css) a little bit, have a look at the fiddle.
The root to all evil is probably because the link stays on focus.. so bluring it after clicking is probably necessary.

http://jsfiddle.net/006L4uof/5/

```
$('#text').on('click', function(e){
    $(this).blur(); //remove focus from clicked link
    $('#dialog').dialog({
        height: 200,
        width: 200,
        modal:true,
        closeText:"close"
        });
    });
```

Let me know if it doesn't work as intended.

Comment: Thank you! Just with `$(this).blur();` it works perfectly :) thanks again